# Use gradient color in Highchart solidgauge

Tags: highcharts

```
$(function () {

    var gaugeOptions = {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // The speed gauge
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: 'Speed'
            }            
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [75]
        }]

    }));
});
```

Using the Highchart's solidgauge. Is there a way to have a gradient color up to the value showing on the gauge?

For example if my gauge is from 0 to 100, and at a specific time the value we are showing is 75, I want to show it as a gradient color transitioning from a green left section to small red right section. Of course the remaining 25% of the gauge in this example should not have any color just showing the background color of the gauge.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, because on the yAxis you define colors only as hex.

Comment: @alloyoussef, please do not open duplicate questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highchart's solid gauge with gradient color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019078/highcharts-solid-gauge-with-gradient-color)

Comment: This works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240478/highcharts-solidgauge-with-green-yellow-red-gradient